# mysql left join : data from left table duplicated for every match

Tags: python, mysql, sql, left-join

I have a simple structure like so:

Challenges table

```
id | title
-----------------
5  | My challenge woo
```

Goals table

```
id  | title         | challenge_id
-------------------------------------
35  | My goal here  | 5
38  | My goal here  | 5
39  | My goal here  | 5
40  | My goal here  | 5
```

Every challenge has multiple goals. If I try something like so:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, g.id, g.title FROM challenges%s as c LEFT JOIN goals%s as g ON c.id=g.challenge_id WHERE c.id=%s
```

I get a copy of the challenge for every single goal that matche, which is tons of data I don't want every time. For example, this is the result :

```
({'g.id': 35L, 'g.title': u'My goal here', 'id': 5L, 'title': u'My challenge woo'}, {'g.id': 38L, 'g.title': u'My goal here', 'id': 5L, 'title': u'My challenge woo'}, {'g.id': 39L, 'g.title': u'My goal here', 'id': 5L, 'title': u'My challenge woo'}, {'g.id': 40L, 'g.title': u'Another goal', 'id': 5L, 'title': u'My challenge woo'})
```

Notice how each instance of the challenge is part of the dictionary? I know mysql doesn't have any arrays, but I've tried CONCAT without any luck, as well as other similar queries such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288863/left-outer-join-with-no-duplicates-on-left-table).

FYI I'm using mysqldb /w python

Comment: You are expecting a single SQL query to return a hierarchical data set?

Comment: That's basically the idea of using `JOIN` in the first place. If you don't want that you should query goals and challenges in two separate, consecutive queries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do an aggregation after the `join`, with `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, group_concat(ws_concat(':', g.id, g.title), separator ', ') as goals
FROM challenges c LEFT JOIN
     goals g
     ON c.id = g.challenge_id
WHERE c.id=%s
GROUP BY c.id, c.title;
```

This will create a list of goals on each line, with the form "id:title".